# How to detect when an Audio Device is disconnected in CoreAudio?

Tags: macos, core-audio, device

Is there a way to set up a listener for any Audio Device to detect if it's been removed or unplugged? I found this post which helps if you only care about built-in audio related devices:

[How to get notifications when the headphones are plugged in/out? Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483083/how-to-get-notifications-when-the-headphones-are-plugged-in-out-mac/14490863#14490863)

But I'm looking for a more universal solution (i.e. all devices, USB, HDMI, etc.). And it's OSX specific.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out! One just needs to add a listener to the appropriate AudioDeviceID (the device you wish to monitor):

```
// add listener for detecting when a device is removed
const AudioObjectPropertyAddress alive_address =
{
  kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsAlive,
  kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
  kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};

AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(current_device_id_, &alive_address, deviceIsAliveCallback, &player_);
```

And then write the corresponding callback:

```
OSStatus deviceIsAliveCallback(AudioObjectID                       inObjectID,
                           UInt32                              inNumberAddresses,
                           const AudioObjectPropertyAddress    inAddresses[],
                           void*                               inClientData)
{
  // your code here
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What about device connection listener?