# How to detect whether headphone is connected to Mac or disconnected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, detect

As is known,you can easily get to know whether the headphone is connected to iOS devices.But I fail to find information about when it is applied to Mac.But some apps like VOX.app(which is an amazing music app)can detect it.For example,VOX may send a notification when the headphone is disconnected.
Please give me some hints and I will appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893390/944634

Answer (score 0):

The headphone port is represented as its own audio device. You can detect if it is the current default audio device.

> The [CAPlayThrough](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html) example project provides a Cocoa based sample
>   application for obtaining all possible input and output devices on the
>   system, setting the default device for input and/or output, and
>   playing through audio from the input device to the output.