# How to determine when a headphone or bluetooth headset is plugged in or connected to a Mac with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, headphones

I'm trying to build a tiny **macOS** App with **Swift**. Now I have some trouble on how to determine when a headphone or bluetooth headset is plugged in or connected to a Mac.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update: I found an answer (posted as bellowing), but it's written with Objective-C. Anyone can help to convert it to Swift? (I tried, but got too much errors)

Comment: There is a solution for Objective C.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893244/how-to-detect-something-in-headphone-jack-on-a-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1

I used that in an app of mine

Comment: Use AVCaptureSession.

Comment: @chronikum Thanks, man. I did check this link before asking for help. But it seems that AVAudioSession is (currently) only available for iOS, but not for macOS. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

Comment: @El Tomato Hi El, could you please share more details? It seems AVCaptureSeesion is used to perform a real-time or offline capture.